# Problems with making a discord bot that reacts to a certain person

Tags: python, discord

As the title says, I'm trying to make a discord bot for my server. I've set it up to react to messages containing specific words and also reply to some others. But I can't make it always react to a specific person. Here's some of my code:

```
import discord

custom_emojis = ["Thonk","TriHard7","xontros2"]


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def react(message,num):
    for emoji in message.guild.emojis:
        if emoji.name == custom_emojis[num]:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if "example1" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('example1')
    if "example2" in message.content.lower():
        await react(message,0)
    if message.author.id == 'The id of the user':
        await react(message,2)



client.run('TOKEN')
```

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `message.author.id` is an int, but you are comparing it to a string. Remove the quotes around the id and it should work.

Comment: Yeah that was it. I should have checked that but my brain is too fried today. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad I could help :)